# How to bind CmdletBinding parameter to a for loop in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get my CmdletBinding to work in PowerShell.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ParameterSetName='firewallIndex', Position=0)]
[switch]$fwIndex,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName='firewallCommand',Position=0)]
[string]$fwName = ( Read-host "Input Firewall Index" ),

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName='firewallCommand',Position=1)]
[string]$fwCommand = ( Read-host "Input Firewall Command")
)

$allFirewallIps = (Get-Content $dir\firewallips.txt)
```

When I run with the `-fwIndex` switch I only want it to do this, which returns a firewall list with an index

```
for($i=0; $i-le $allFirewallIps.Length-1; $i++)
         {"`[{0}] = {1}” -f $i,$allFirewallIps[$i]}
```

Returns:

```
[0] = 10.1.128.4 fw-ips-labA
[1] = 10.1.128.5 fw-ips-labB
[2] = 10.1.17.128 fw-extranet
[3] = 10.1.17.214 fw-ukdr
[4] = 10.1.17.215 fw-ukvpna
[5] = 10.1.17.216 fw-ukvpnb
```

I tried it with this

```
if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("$fwIndex"))
```

But when I run the command it goes through all of the Cmdlets and I get the `$fwName` and `$fwCommand` parameters asking me to input.

```
fwcommand_run.ps1 -fwIndex
**Input Firewall Index: 
Input Firewall Command:** 
[0] = 10.1.128.4 fw-ips-labA
[1] = 10.1.128.5 fw-ips-labB
[2] = 10.1.17.128 fw-extranet
[3] = 10.1.17.214 fw-ukdr
[4] = 10.1.17.215 fw-ukvpna
[5] = 10.1.17.216 fw-ukvpnb
```

How do I bind the for loop to the `$fwIndex` switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get asked to input for `$fwName`and `$fwCommand` due to the `Read-Host` cmdlet. Just omit them:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ParameterSetName='firewallIndex', Position=0)]
[switch]$fwIndex,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName='firewallCommand',Position=0)]
[string]$fwName,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName='firewallCommand',Position=1)]
[string]$fwCommand
)

$allFirewallIps = (Get-Content $dir\firewallips.txt)
```

You could instead add a `HelpMessage` to your parameter:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName='firewallCommand',Position=0, HelpMessage="Input Firewall Index")]
```

If you now invoke your cmdlet using the *firewallCommand* parameter set, you will get something like this:

```
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
fwName:
```

And if you enter `!?`you will see the help text.

To check, whether the switch is set, just use `$fwIndex.IsPresent`

Comment: Thanks. My main issue is how do I bind the for loop to the `$fwIndex` switch?

Comment: As I wrote, you can use `$fwIndex.IsPresent` to check whether you have to execute the for loop (just use a simple `if`). Or what you mean with bind the for loop?

Comment: When I use `-fwIndex` switch I want it to run the `for` loop and return the list of firewalls. Then I want to use the `-fwName` and `-fwCommand` strings together to run a command against the firewall. So basically you will run  `command.ps1 -fwIndex` and get the firewalls index number. and then run `command.ps1 -fwName "5" -fwCommand "ls" ` which will run the command against the firewall who's index number I have provided - in this example the command **ls** would be run against **[5] = 10.1.17.216 fw-ukvpnb**

Comment: You can do this with an if statement on the switch, mentioned in my answer. However, I wouldn't. You should rather implement two scripts: `Get-FirewallIndex.ps1` and something like `Invoke-FirewallCommand.ps1`